# Getting the return value of __setitem__() and length of dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
class Only5Items(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(self) < 5:
            super(Only5Items, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

I want to return true, if I success to add an item. Any ideas?

I'll explain it a little more.
For example:

```
items = Only5Items()
items["hi1"] = "asdf1"
items["hi2"] = "asdf2"
items["hi3"] = "asdf3"
items["hi4"] = "asdf4"
items["hi5"] = "asdf5"
items["hi6"] = "asdf6"
```

`items["hi6"] = "asdf6"` won't insert. And i want to print a message about it.

edit: len(self) works. And to be more specific, i don't want to print a message about it, i want to return true/false if i success to add it. Something external to the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment doesn't have a return value in Python and the return value of `__setitem__()` is ignored. Generally, you'd want to raise an exception instead:

```
class Only5Items(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(self) < 5 or key in self:   # allow reassignment of existing key
            return super(Only5Items, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        raise KeyError("maximum number of items (5) exceeded")
```

Then your client code can catch the exception:

```
items = Only5Items(hi1="asdf1", hi2="asdf2", hi3="asdf3", hi4="asdf4", hi5="asdf5")
try:
    items["hi6"] = "asdf6"
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```

If you want to return `True/False` then you have to write your own assignment method that *can* return a value:

```
class Only5Items(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(self) < 5 or key in self:   # allow reassignment of existing key
            return super(Only5Items, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        raise KeyError("maximum number of items (5) exceeded")

    def did_set(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key] = value
        except KeyError:
            return False
        return True
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
if not items.did_set("hi6", "asdf6"):
    print "couldn't set key 'hi6', dictionary is probably full"
```

You probably also want to override `setdefault()` to check the number of items too... also, it'd be nice (and pretty easy) to pass in the maximum number when you instantiate the class instead of hard-coding it to 5.

Comment: You didn't mean to use the keyword `return`. Right?

Comment: You mean in `__getitem__()`? It's a habit... I try to always `return` the super class result even if it's not strictly necessary. It won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

Erm, I'd just do the following:

```
class Only5Items(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(self) < 5:
            return super(Only5Items, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        else:
            raise KeyError("You forgot I can only have 5 items dummy!")

    def __str__(self):
        return super(Only5Items, self).__str__()
```

The following script:

```
d = Only5Items(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
print d

try:
    d['making a mistake'] = 'hahahahah'
except KeyError, e:
    print e
```

Produces:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
'You forgot I can only have 5 items dummy!'
```

Comment: I ticked the other. But this one is great as well. and this one is what im gonna use. (the other guy wrote 2 methods).. Thanks alot!!

Comment: @Nirock Hey no problem. Kindall is a revered member of the SO Python community. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Only5Items(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if len(self) < 5:
            super(Only5Items, self).__setitem__(key, value)
            print "Succesfully inserted!"
        else:
            print "Dictionary full!"
```

Comment: Thats a good example to print. but.. I didn't mean it to be like that.. I need to actually "return true/false" other method.

Comment: Replace the print with return True and the else condition to return False?

Comment: Setting a dictionary item doesn't return a value, so returning true or false from `__setitem__()` wouldn't really help.